# change database name in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm newbie on Zend Framework, I've declared database configure :
***resources.db.params.host = 'localhost'

resources.db.params.username = 'root'

resources.db.params.password = ''

resources.db.params.dbname = 'zftutorial'***

I created some pages through this, but now I want to change database name ,How to not to change to multiple databases and just using one database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you changing your dbname in [production] , [staging : production] , [testing : production] , [development : production] ?